# How to write interface for a specific use case in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a use case in TS Project(No React) where i have a interface as below:

```
export interface LayerStyling<T> {
    attribute: string;
    value: AllowedTypes;
    type: LayerTypes;
    layout?: {
        icon: string
    };
    state: {
        [key in States]: ObjectType<T>
    }
}
```

Where LayerTypes can be of two type's  "default" | "icon" based on that "layout" key will exist in this LayerStyling interface.

If LayerTypes = "default" interface will be

```
export interface LayerStyling<T> {
    attribute: string;
    value: AllowedTypes;
    type: LayerTypes;
    state: {
        [key in States]: ObjectType<T>
    }
}
```

If LayerTypes = "icon" interface will be

```
export interface LayerStyling<T> {
    attribute: string;
    value: AllowedTypes;
    type: LayerTypes;
    layout: {
        icon: string
    };
    state: {
        [key in States]: ObjectType<T>
    }
}
```

Based on "LayerTypes" "layout" key will toggle.

How to handle this usecase? As when I write below code:

```
const { layout: { icon } } = attrs; // It throws an error Property 'icon' does not exist on type '{ icon: string; } | undefined'.
```

Please guide me here!

Comment: It seems like you want a [*union*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types), `type LayerStyling<T> = { type: "default", ... } | { type: "icon", layout: { icon: string }, ... }`. Then you can [*use type guards*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) to narrow the type when you know you've got an icon.

Comment: Thank you!! @jonrsharpe I got the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
type LayerTypes = 'default' | 'icon';
type AllowedTypes = string;
type States = 'a' | 'b';
interface ObjectType<T> {

}

export interface LayerStyling<T> {
  attribute: string;
  value: AllowedTypes;
  state: {
    [key in States]: ObjectType<T>
  };
  // type: LayerTypes; // optional
}

export interface LayerStylingDefault<T> extends LayerStyling<T> {
  type: 'default';
}

export interface LayerStylingIcon<T> extends LayerStyling<T> {
  type: 'icon';
  layout: {
    icon: string;
  };
}

const myIcon: LayerStylingIcon<number> = {
  attribute: '',
  value: '',
  state: {a: '', b: ''},
  type: 'icon',
  layout: {
    icon: '',
  },
};

const myDefault: LayerStylingDefault<number> = {
  attribute: '',
  value: '',
  state: {a: '', b: ''},
  type: 'default',
};

// Another syntax
export type LayerStylingDefault2<T> = LayerStyling<T> & {type: 'default'};
export type LayerStylingIcon2<T> = LayerStyling<T> & {
  type: 'icon';
  layout: {
    icon: string;
  };
};

const myDefault2: LayerStylingDefault2<number> = myDefault;
const myIcon2: LayerStylingIcon2<number> = myIcon;

// You might want to know how to make type guards.
// https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards
function isLayerStylingIcon(e: LayerStylingDefault<any> | LayerStylingIcon<any>): e is LayerStylingIcon<any> {
  return e.type === 'icon';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are getting the correct error message because icon is optional field.
When you de-structure **LayerStyling**, you have take that into consideration.

You can do this as follows:

```js
// below typeof icon will be string | undefined
const { layout: { icon } = {} } = attr

if (icon != undefined) {
  console.log('LayerTypes was icon')
} else {
  console.log('LayerTypes was default')
}
```